# read 2d array into triangle

Tags: java, arrays

I want to read the following into a 2d jagged array:

```
3
7 4
2 4 6
8 5 9 3
```

I need to increase the column size on every input. I'm not exactly sure how to do it.

My code is as follows:

```
int col = 1;
int[][] values = new int[rows][col];
for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
  for(int j = 1; j < col; j++)
  {
     values[i][j] = kb.nextInt();
     col++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use arrays? They may not be the best data-structure for this, depending on what you want to do with the data once you've read it in.

Comment: inreasing column size is not problem, you are also increasing row size, that's the problem and hence you  need a dynamic list.

Comment: You can also use a single array to keep all the data. Then write a function to find the 2D index of the array based on the single index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it.

```
int[][] values = new int[rows][];
for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
    values[i] = new int[i+1];

    for(int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++)
    {
        values[i][j] = kb.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Basically, you start by defining how many rows your 2d array should have.

In the `for` loop, you define the 1d array for each row with its length.

Comment: @davida. I'll wait some seconds before adding my next answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sample

```
// don't fix the second dimension
int[][] values = new int[rows][];

for(i = 0; i < rows;i ++){
    //column size increases for every line input
    values[i] = new int[i+1];

    for(j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
         values[i][j] = kb.nextInt();
    }
}
```

In Java, arrays do not have to be strictly rectangular. The variable `values` is a `rows`-element array of references to `int` arrays. Here, `values[0]` is a 1-element `int` array, values[1] is a 2-element `int` array, etc.

Comment: You should change `col` in the inner `for` loop to something more appropriate.

Comment: @o_o.. For God sake, let those `=` and `+` and `;` breath some air.. If they die, we cannot live too.. This time I've done it for you..